# DOS command redirect to file truncates output

Tags: redirect, buffer, dos

I have a command line tool that typically dumps out about 200+ lines of output.  I'm looking for text that appears at the end of this output.  When I redirect the output to a file:

```
C:\> somecommand > results.txt 2>&1
```

...only the first 100 or so lines of output shows up in this file.  Likewise, if I pipe the output into something like 'findstr', the receiving program is unable to find or operate on any text after about the 100th line.

The screen buffer size settings for the shell appear to have no effect whatsoever on the number of lines that can be captured.

Any ideas what is going on here?  For what it's worth, the command in question is iscmdbld.exe from InstallShield 2012.

This problem does not occur with other commands I've tried (such as 'dir').

The full output from the program can only be viewed when running the command within a cmd window.

Comment: try the redirection at the start, just incase the command is treating it as a parameter - `> results.txt 2>&1 somecommand`

Comment: Try appending the output:    C:\> somecommand >> results.txt 2>&1

Comment: I have the same program with my own Visual C++ project. The output of my program gets truncated when redirected to a file.

Comment: program (1st occurence) -> problem

Comment: My truncated output is a google-test output where I have 50+ test subjects with 200+ test functions total.

Answer (score 3):

Well unfortunately I do not have InstallShield installed so it will be quite hard for me to run some test, but I have cam across programs that are not acting as they supposed to do when it comes to handling input and output. In a normal case ">" should have NO limit, I'm using it a lot on a windows server which is running ghostscript and other old dos programs in the background and the only way to pipe the output to a file is to use >, sometimes I have files of quite a few Mb, so the 200 lines really has to do something with the current exe.

I can only suggest to try some workaround, for example you can try tee32, it's a small freeware which will capture all the dos screen output to a file. So you will see the output on the screen and you will have it in file too.

You can read more about it: [**here**](http://freesoft.cyberside.net.ee/FreeSoft/screen.htm) unfortunately the links mentioned on the page are not working, but I was able to find a working copy of it: [**here**](http://reimagery.com/fsfd/bin/friesen/32-bit/tee32.zip)

I really hope this will help you overcome the problem.

Emil

Comment: The problem was very tricky. My program terminated in an ill but seemingly good manner. There is nothing wrong (Win 7 64bit) with redirecting the console. But I liked this answer very much as it gives way to debug problems like this.

Comment: Thanks. I started using computers with MS-DOS 5.0 and Windows 3.0 when I was about 8 - 10, and somehow DOS and all the small workarounds those limitations (like 640kb RAM) are still may favorite subject, it had it's own magic and I still think DOS has some interesting feel you will never get in neither LINUX, neither any fancy Windows.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to your problem might be building an C# program that captures the output and sends it to a file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CaptureCMDOutput
{
    class Program
    {
        static string _Filename = @"sc.exe";
        static string _Arguments = @"query";
        static string _outputfile = @"c:\debug.txt";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = _Filename, // Exe file to run
                Arguments = _Arguments, // Arguments to exe file
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            process.OutputDataReceived += process_OutputDataReceived;
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            process.WaitForExit();
            process.CancelOutputRead();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void process_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_outputfile, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it is writing to another stream, try this:

```
somecommand > results.txt 2>&1 3>&1 4>&1 5>&1 6>&1 7>&1 8>&1 9>&1
```

The other possibility is that the tool is using direct-screen-writes for part of the output - in MSDOS days there were screen reading TSR programs that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Another tack is to append ('>>') rather start fresh ('>'). However, I cannot think how to even generate what you are seeing without knowing more about your issue.

Comment: Failed to produce a small reproduction program. The original effect is in place in the original situation. Adding more info to my case in the comment of the question.